# Whats wrong with instant client? | cx_Oracle.Database: ORA-12514

Tags: linux, database, oracle, ubuntu-14.04, cx-oracle

With the help of `cx_Oracle` package I am trying to connect to remote Oracle database. Unfortunately I have error when try to test next python code:

```
import cx_Oracle;
dsn_tns=cx_Oracle.makedsn('HOST', 'PORT', service_name='NAME')
connection=cx_Oracle.connect('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', dsn_tns)
```

**ERROR**:

```
cx_Oracle.Database: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

**Dependencies**:

1) Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) (local computer)

2) Python 2.7.14 (64 bit)

3) cx_Oracle 6.4.1

4) Instant Client 18.3

5) Oracle 11g database (located in remote server)

I used [official](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) documentation to install and configurate instant client.

Official documentation say that:

> Oracle Call Interface 18.3 can connect to Oracle Database 11.2 or
>   later.

For thats why I load basic package of instant client 18.3, then unzip it:

```
cd /opt/oracle          
unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-18.3.0.0.0dbru.zip
```

Then I install `libaio`:

```
sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

In terminal I wrote next 2 command:

```
sudo sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
sudo ldconfig
```

Inside `/opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3/network/admin` I put `tnsnames.ora` file.

After that I set environment variable in `~/.profile`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3/network/admin
export PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_18_3:$PATH
```

What else should I have done to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with instant client? Absolutely nothing from the information you supplied. You are connecting to the server (listener) but the server is not configured with the database you specified.
You can confirm this with a different client / different client host.

Go check the config on the server.

Comment: Hello, I am confused. Settings inside `tnsnames.ora` file is correct. What kind of specific settings (config) I miss in my computer?

Comment: **NOTHING - THE PROBLEM IS ON THE SERVER**